# python urllib2 hangs when invoked by apache

Tags: apache-2.2, http, python

I have a python script that reads a resource using urllib2 like so

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
html = response.read()
response.close()
```

which works fine when invoked in a terminal. However, when invoked by an apache server  (i.e., pointing to the script with a browser), it just hangs on the urlopen. Any ideas why that is?

FWIW, there's no change in behavior if I spoof a mozilla user agent, or pass an empty dict for proxy handlers.  Setting http debug level to 1 also gives no more information, but I added tracers that demonstrate that it is in fact the 'urlopen' line that hangs.

Thanks, Nick

(full disclosure, this is a cross-post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399794/urllib2-urlopen-hangs-when-invoked-by-apache-server).  Hope that's legal- it's been over a week with no answer)

Comment: I am having the same problem.. did you in the end manage to find the reason of this?